What remedies are available if someone brings a lawsuit that violates an arbitration clause?
Say I sign a contract with someone saying that, in exchange for $500, I promise to lend them my lawnmower once a month for the entire summer, with a clause saying that if we have a dispute, we aren't going to settle it in court, and instead we agree to settle it in arbitration.
Then when they come to borrow the lawnmower in July, I refuse to give it to them. They don't like this, so they sue me in court. I get served with paperwork that a civil suit has been opened against me. Now we're both in breach of the contract: I didn't hand over the lawnmower, which I promised to do, and they sued me, which they promised not to do.
What remedies are available to me for being sued by someone who promised not to do it? Are they civilly liable to pay my legal fees? Are they liable for the negative consequences to me of the court's decisions? Would the court, when presented with the contract, just throw out the case because they had promised not to bring it?
This is probably state-specific; I'm interested in answers about any state. There are other questions about whether and when arbitration agreements are enforceable, but I wasn't able to find one about how specifically it can be enforced.

Did they pay the $500 yet?

@Barmar Yes, assume they paid already.

And the case wasn't dismissed because of the arbitration clause?

@Barmar That's the meat of the question I'm asking. Is the case going to be dismissed or something, and if so how/why?

Since the whole point of arbitration agreements is to avoid going to court, it seems likely to me, but I don't know how this is addressed. Although it seems like the simple solution is to just return the money.

Some rules, like AAA (R-9) allow small claims court, which would likely be the only reasonable court venue for a $500 dispute.

@Barmar Depending on the case it can be possible to ask the court to reject the arbitration clause and continue the case in court.  I might have personal experience in this /s

Most often you would file a motion to stay the lawsuit and refer to case to arbitration. Then, when the arbitration was over, the enforcement of the arbitration award would be in the case that has been stayed.
There are slight variations in exactly what is filed where, however, depending upon the state where the suit is filed.
Any fees or sanctions would be awarded by an arbitrator, who is largely lawless and unfettered from any way to be compelled to follow the law.

You file the relevant defence
That being that there is a binding agreement to arbitrate and you ask the court to dismiss their lawsuit.

or adjudicate if the arbitration clause is binding (and dismiss for cause then)

I think the OP is concerned about the costs of mounting this defense, as the point of the arbitration clause was to avoid it. Assuming the case is dismissed, are they likely to be able to recover them?

@Barbar The arbitrator will decide.
